# Filter data.frame by date range in R

Tags: r

I have a DF like this:

```
Date <- c("10/17/17","11/11/17","11/23/17","11/25/17","12/3/17","12/10/17","12/16/17")
Ben <- c("1294",NA,"8959","2345",NA,"0303",NA)
James <- c(NA,"4523","3246",NA,"2394","8877","1427")
Alex <- c("3754","1122","5582",NA,"0094",NA,NA)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Ben,James,Alex)

#df1
Date          Ben     James     Alex
10/17/17      1294    NA        3754
11/11/17      NA      4523      1122
11/23/17      8959    3246      5582
11/25/17      2345    NA        NA
12/3/17       NA      2394      0094
12/10/17      0303    8877      NA
12/16/17      NA      1427      NA
```

As you can see, the DF is sorted by date. I'm trying to put values that are within 2 weeks of the latest date for each column into a new DF, like this:

```
#df2
Ben     James     Alex
0303    1427      0094
NA      8877      5582
NA      2394      NA
```

Ben only has one listed value because there's only one non NA value within 2 weeks of 12/10/17, the latest date that has a non NA value in Ben's column. James's latest non NA date is 12/16/17. He has three values that fall within two weeks of that date: 1427, 8877 and 2394. Alex's latest date is 12/3/17. He has two values within two weeks of his latest date: 0094 and 5582. The number of rows that the new data.frame has should be equal to the column that is longest. Columns with fewer entries within their respective two week ranges should use NA to fill in data, like Ben's column.

I'm currently using the following code, which simply filters the last 3 non NA in each column:

`df2 <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], n = 3))`

Comment: Please, share your dataset in a reproducible way (using `dput` function).

Comment: Can you give a complete output that you would like to see from the example above? I also see the dates `11/23/17` and `11/29/17` being within two weeks and `11/29/17` and `12/10/17` are also within two weeks yet `12/10/17` and `11/23/17` are not within two weeks.. So please specify what exacty you need and how you need it

Comment: df2 represents the complete output that I'm looking for based on the data given in df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using base r to be subset:

```
lapply(df1[-1],function(x)x[which((m<-tail(df1$Date[!is.na(x)],1)-df1$Date)>=0&m<=14)])->result
max(lengths(result))->len 
do.call(cbind.data.frame,lapply(result,`length<-`,len))

    Ben James Alex
1 <NA>  2394 5582
2 0303  8877 <NA>
3 <NA>  1427 0094
```

I just realized those are coded as characters according to the data you gave

To have it exactly as given in the expected results, we would have:

```
 do.call(cbind.data.frame,lapply(result,function(x) `length<-`(rev(x),len)))
  Ben James Alex
1 0303  1427 0094
2 <NA>  8877 <NA>
3 <NA>  2394 5582
```

Comment: this is close, but takes data from within two weeks of the latest date of all columns, which isn't quite what I want. Alex's data should include 0094 and 5582 because both of those are within two weeks of his most recent data point, 0094 on 11/29/17.

I'm trying something like this, but can't get it to work:

`df2 <- lapply(df1[-1],function(x) subset(df1,(tail(Date,1)-Date<=14)))`

Comment: I now understand what you mean

Comment: this appears to only be listing two rows of data: either the first or the last within the two week range. While the sample data that I provided doesn't have a column in the output of more than two rows, my actual data can produce an output that has more than two rows.

Comment: Well in that case, I guess you will have  to give a different example that satisfy your needs.Since here we did produce the desired output

Comment: I've updated my data. Notice how the output leaves out James's "8877" because it only shows the first and last entries within the date range, and "8877" falls on a date between the first and the last. I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Whether I well understood what you are looking for, the following code will help you:

I have loaded your dataset (with `dput` function)

```
dataset <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17456, 17481, 17493, 17495, 
17499, 17510, 17516), class = "Date"), Ben = c(1294L, NA, 8959L, 
2345L, NA, 303L, NA), James = c(NA, 4523L, 3246L, NA, NA, 8877L, 
1427L), Alex = c(3754L, 1122L, 5582L, NA, 94L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Ben", "James", "Alex"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then load the following packages:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

Fix `last_date` and change format to `Date` variable:

```
last_date <- mdy("12/16/17")
dataset$Date <- mdy(dataset$Date)
```

Now, let's select only rows you want:

```
dataset_filtered <- dataset %>% 
    filter(Date<=last_date & Date>=(last_date-days(14)))
```

You'll have:

```
        Date Ben James Alex
1 2017-12-10 303  8877   NA
2 2017-12-16  NA  1427   NA
```

Please, next time use `dput` function, not always is Xmas ;-)